# Forwarded packet seemingly, skipping POSTROUTING rules

Tags: router, iptables, wireguard, ufw, nftables

I have a very simple Wireguard configuration. Client are assigned `10.7.0.0/24` addressed, traffic is forwarded out the primary interface, finally the packets are SNAT'd out of the primary interface on '192.168.1.0/24'. Everything seems to be working except that last step and I cannot even trigger a `LOG` rule in the POSTROUTING table.

The TRACE output for a ping to `192.168.1.185` from `10.7.0.2` is below:

```
kernel: [  524.154478] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=wg0 OUT= MAC= SRC=10.7.0.2 DST=192.168.1.185 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=7783 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=542
kernel: [  524.154502] TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:1 IN=wg0 OUT=ens192 MAC= SRC=10.7.0.2 DST=192.168.1.185 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=7783 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=542
kernel: [  524.154507] IN=wg0 OUT=ens192 MAC= SRC=10.7.0.2 DST=192.168.1.185 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=7783 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=542
kernel: [  524.154512] TRACE: filter:FORWARD:rule:3 IN=wg0 OUT=ens192 MAC= SRC=10.7.0.2 DST=192.168.1.185 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=7783 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=542
```

I see the LOG rule in `filter:FORWARD:rule:1` is triggered correctly and the packets gets to `filter:FORWARD:rule:3`. This makes sense.

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 92 packets, 4848 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4   240 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.185        LOG flags 0 level 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  430 28493 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.7.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
```

**What I don't understand is why there is no POSTROUTING rules triggered after this. Not even a LOG rule is triggered. Why is this?**

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.185        LOG flags 0 level 4
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      *       10.7.0.0/24         !10.7.0.0/24          to:192.168.1.124
```

### Update: `iptables`

Here is the complete iptables rules:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [26:2369]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 10.7.0.0/24 ! -d 10.7.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.124
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu May 18 00:16:56 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Thu May 18 00:16:56 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [3598:452715]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [12:720]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2685:370730]
[240:33000] -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 52160 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[228:15470] -A FORWARD -s 10.7.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

#### NFtables

```
sudo nft list ruleset
table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        }
}
```

## Update: Started Working, but Why?

I was looking at other iptables rules and then everything started to work. The iptables-save is below. Right now I have two theories:

1. The nat table is only looked at for 'new' connection, not sure how a connection is considered new or not
2. By listing the rules of 'mangle' it created the table and altered the behavior of the system?

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Thu May 18 00:48:19 2023
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6532:813762]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4430:674431]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu May 18 00:48:19 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Thu May 18 00:48:19 2023
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [12837:1592394]
:INPUT ACCEPT [11726:1478490]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1111:113904]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8651:1277974]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [9762:1391878]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu May 18 00:48:19 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Thu May 18 00:48:19 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1678:159704]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1932:186621]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4667:280576]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4674:280996]
[110:7552] -A POSTROUTING -s 10.7.0.0/24 ! -d 10.7.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.124
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu May 18 00:48:19 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Thu May 18 00:48:19 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [19546:2623783]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [502:28104]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [15543:2246022]
[1835:264832] -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 52160 -j ACCEPT
[1136:122259] -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[533:36117] -A FORWARD -s 10.7.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu May 18 00:48:19 2023
```

Comment: To avoid any inaccurate understanding, can you provide the complete ruleset, using `iptables-save -c` *and* `nftables list ruleset` which will include iptables but possibly more (yes WireGuard will use nftables if available when used in its usual default mode: AllowedIPs = 0/0 + Table = auto). Likewise, you should provide the WireGuard configuration (just obfuscate the keys): this would help understand too.

Comment: `The nat table is only looked at for 'new' connection, not sure how a connection is considered new or not` Found a related answer that happened to be posted by @A.B: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524320